# What is the proper use case for AppCompatCallback?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

[The revision notes](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) mention `AppCompatCallback` needs to be implemented to be able to perform callbacks. [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatCallback.html) cryptically state "Implemented this in order for AppCompat to be able to callback in certain situations."

What are those certain situations? Is this something only support library Activities or Fragments need? What is the proper use case for `AppCompatCallback`?

Comment: I guess so, since evey methods in it are abstract..